# More "pythonic" way to show a 4d matrix in 2d

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I would like to plot a 4d matrix as a 2d matrix with indices:

```
[i][j][k][l] --> [i * nj + j][ k * nl + l]
```

I have a working version [here](https://github.com/rappoccio/QJetMassUproot/blob/master/example_2d_response_creation.ipynb).

This is working as I want, but it's not very elegant. I looked into "reshape" but this is not exactly what I'm looking for, or perhaps I am using it incorrectly.

Given a 4d array "r" with shape (100000,4), the relevant snippet I want to replace is:

```py
def transform(i,j,k,l, s1, s2):
    return [i * s1 + j, k * s2 + l]

nx = 5
ny = 11
iedges=np.linspace(0,100, nx)
jedges=np.linspace(0, 20, ny)
bins = ( iedges,jedges,iedges,jedges )

H, edges = np.histogramdd(r, bins=bins )

H2 = np.zeros(( (nx-1)*(ny-1),(nx-1)*(ny-1)))
for i in range(nx-1):
    for j in range(ny-1):
        for k in range(nx-1):
            for l in range(ny-1):
                x,y = transform(i,j,k,l,ny-1,ny-1)                
                H2[x][y] = H[i][j][k][l]
```

In this case the values of H2 will correspond to the values of H, but the entry

```
i,j,k,l
```

will display as

```
i*ny + j, k * ny + l
```

.

Example plot:

[image: 4d matrix represented as 2d matrix]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can calculate `i,j,k,l` from `x,y`? This should be something like:

```py
from functools import partial

def get_ijkl(x, y, s1, s2):
    # "Reverse" of `transform`
    i, j = divmod(x, s1)
    k, l = divmod(y, s2)
    return (i, j, k, l)


def get_2d_val(x, y, s1, s2, four_dim_array):
    return four_dim_array[get_ijkl(x, y, s1, s2)]


smaller_shape = ((nx-1)*(ny-1), (nx-1)*(ny-1))
```

Knowing this there are several approaches possible:

- [`numpy.fromfunction`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html?highlight=fromfunction#numpy.fromfunction):

```py
H3 = np.fromfunction(
    partial(get_2d_val, s1=ny-1, s2=ny-1, four_dim_array=H),
    shape=smaller_shape,
    dtype=int,
)
assert np.all(H2 == H3)
```

- by  [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing):

```py
indices_to_take = np.array([
    [list(get_ijkl(x, y, ny-1, ny-1)) for x in range(smaller_shape[0])] for y in range(smaller_shape[1])
]).transpose()
H4 = H[tuple(indices_to_take)]
assert np.all(H2 == H4)
```

- as answered by @hpaulj you can simply reshape array and it will be faster. But If you have some different `transform` and can calculate appropriate "reverse" function then using `fromfunction` or custom indexing will get useful

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful, I understand how the transformations are done now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `reshape` doesn't work?

I ran your code on a small random `r`.  The nonzero terms of `H` are:

```
In [13]: np.argwhere(H)                                                                                  
Out[13]: 
array([[0, 9, 3, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 1, 8]])
```

and for the transformed `H2`:

```
In [14]: np.argwhere(H2)                                                                                 
Out[14]: 
array([[ 9, 31],
       [11, 12],
       [12, 13],
       [22, 23],
       [31, 18]])
```

And one of the `H` indices transforms to `H2` indices with:

```
In [16]: transform(0,9,3,1,4,10)                                                                         
Out[16]: [9, 31]
```

If I simply reshape `H`, I get the same array as `H2`:

```
In [17]: H3=H.reshape(40,40)                                                                             
In [18]: np.argwhere(H3)                                                                                 
Out[18]: 
array([[ 9, 31],
       [11, 12],
       [12, 13],
       [22, 23],
       [31, 18]])
In [19]: np.allclose(H2,H3)                                                                              
Out[19]: True
```

So without delving into the details of your code, it looks to me like a simple reshape.

Comment: Thank you! I did manage to get it working, I was indeed using "reshape" incorrectly. Thanks for the help.